# asp.net calendar control appears below textfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, calendar

I ma using an image button to display an asp.net calendar control (this control comes with VS 2008). However, when I click the image button, the calendar controls is displayed "below" the textfield that it is suppoed to populate. How can I get the control to appear on the right side of the textfield?

My code is:

```
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendar" runat="server" Height="17px" 
                         ImageUrl="~/Images/CAL.gif" 
                         onclick="imgCalendar_Click1" Width="19px" 
                         Visible="true" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                         <asp:Calendar ID="calStartDate" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" 
                             BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px" DayHeaderStyle-BackColor="gainsboro" 
                             DayNameFormat="Shortest" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Font-Bold="True" 
                             Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Gray" Height="102px" 
                             OnSelectionChanged="calStartDate_SelectionChanged" 
                             OtherMonthDayStyle-ForeColor="gray" SelectedDayStyle-BackColor="Navy" 
                             SelectedDayStyle-Font-Bold="True" SelectorStyle-BackColor="gainsboro" 
                             ShowGridLines="True" TitleStyle-BackColor="gray" TitleStyle-Font-Bold="True" 
                             TitleStyle-Font-Size="12px" TodayDayStyle-BackColor="gainsboro" Visible="False" Width="62px">
                             <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#404040" Font-Bold="True" />
                             <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#3A080B" ForeColor="White" />
                             <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                             <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
                             <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#3A080B" />
                             <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#3A080B" Font-Bold="True" Height="1px" ForeColor="White" />
                             <TitleStyle BackColor="#E0C16B" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#3A080B" />
                         </asp:Calendar>
                     </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I'd suggest that you set the `CssClass` property of the `asp:Panel` and position it using CSS.  The HTML generated by the control likely renders block level elements (either `<div>` or `<table>` most likely) which will cause it to display on a new line by default.

Try using `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` or using `float` to position it.

Depending on the way you've styled your textbox, you may need to modify it's styles too to accommodate the positioning of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Add style="float:right" to the textbox.

Comment: textbox does not have a style property.

Comment: It does - it just doesn't appear in the Intellisense.  You can still use a style tag on the textbox though.  Besides, I think Fat_Tony's answer should sort your problem.

Comment: You can still style it, via CssClass attribute